# Copy file from another branch without commit using a single git command

Tags: git, branch

It is possible to copy a file from one branch to another without the destination being committed, for example:

```
$ git checkout otherbranch somefile
$ git reset HEAD somefile
```

However, can the above be done with a *single* `git` command?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason behind the single-command limit?

Comment: Idle curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

```
git cat-file --filters -p otherbranch:somefile > somefile
```

`otherbranch:somefile` refers to the blob of `somefile` on `otherbranch`.

`git cat-file -p` prints the content of the blob.

`> somefile` overwrites `somefile` in the worktree with the content.

As @jthill commented, `--filters` should be used in case any filter is configured and `somefile` is affected. `git lfs` is one of the use cases.

Comment: Consider the `--filters` option if you've got lfs or anything that processes the repository content on the way to the worktree , `git cat-file --filters -p other:path >path`.

Comment: @jthill thanks. I've never used filters in practice before. It should be considered.